# TTY1 shows passwords

Tags: password, security, tty

I am using 4.15.0-106-generic (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) alongside Windows 8.1 for over a year.

I usually use `TTY4-TT6` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, etc. Just now, I accidently went to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and was shocked to observe my password at the end of screen. The screen appears momentarily before moving to login screen ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>). The screen has other entries similar to those seen during start-up and command line shutdown (`dmesg`).

Is this a known security vulnerability or is my system compromised?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release details (that kernel could be one one of two OSes not counting changes made by users post-install). No I would not expect to see a password, but you've provided few details (no OS/release, nor if using a server? desktop? flavor?...)

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I'm using it as a desktop.

Comment: 'uname -srv' gives the following output : Linux 4.15.0-106-generic #107-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 4 11:27:52 UTC 2020

Comment: `uname` gives kernel details, but not your OS/release details. `lsb_release -a` will list that (even if LSB isn't installed) among other ways

Comment: Output from lsb_release -a :

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Your system is well behind on updates/upgrades.. It should report 18.04.4 with all upgrades applied, so `sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade` to ensure all upgrades are installed, then you'll likely need to reboot, then see if it still occurs... *Your system is responding as if you've not upgraded packages since before 2019-February-15 - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/02/15/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-released/*

Comment: I've updated, yet to get the same problem as before. I'll update here in case the problem reappears.

Thank you!